# VBA Automated Login: URL Changes After First Use Resulting in Error

Tags: excel, vba

Code posted below. After alot of trying I managed to scrape together a macro that it will auto-log me into my bank account. If I try to run it a second time, the URL changes on me and I get an error message. If I clear my browsing history and close/re-open the file, it works again. I've tried setting my Internet Options to "Delete Browsing History on Exit". I also tried changing "Dim IE As InternetExplorer" to"Dim IE As InternetExplorerMedium" because I read somewhere that that might help. Something having to do with this being a secure site and it was redirecting me to a parent URL. Does anyone know what could be causing this and how I can fix it? I've asked around on the other forums but have had no luck with a response. Would greatly appreciate some help. Tks.

Note: I'm being redirected from https://chaseonline.chase.com/  to https://www.chase.com/

Have searched the internet looking for solutions. Have tried to get help on other forums but have been unsuccessful. Have tried fixing it myself but since I don't know what is the root cause, I don't know what to fix.

Sub Chase()

```
Const cURL = "https://chaseonline.chase.com/"
Const cUserID = "XXXXXX"
Const cPassword = "XXXXXX"

Dim IE As InternetExplorer
Dim doc As HTMLDocument
Dim LoginForm As HTMLFormElement
Dim UsernameInputBox As HTMLInputElement
Dim PasswordInputBox As HTMLInputElement
Dim LogOnButton As HTMLInputButtonElement
Dim HTMLelement As IHTMLElement
Dim qt As QueryTable

Set IE = New InternetExplorer

IE.Visible = True
IE.navigate cURL

'Wait for initial page to load

Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE Or IE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop

Set doc = IE.document

'Get the only form on the page

Set LoginForm = doc.forms(0)

'Get the Username textbox and populate it
'input name="UserID" id="UserID" size="18" value="" class="user-name" type="text"

Set UsernameInputBox = doc.getElementById("UserID")
UsernameInputBox.Value = cUserID

'Get the Password textbox and populate it
'input name="Password" id="Password" size="18" class="user-password" type="password"


Set PasswordInputBox = doc.getElementById("Password")
PasswordInputBox.Value = cPassword

'Get the form input button and click it

Set LogOnButton = doc.getElementById("logon")
LogOnButton.Click

'Wait for the new page to load

Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE Or IE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop

End Sub
```

success

Comment: How are you running it the second time? Are you just calling the sub again? Side note: these sites are built so that user cannot automate processes on it because of security risks.. technically you are breaking the terms and conditions of site use :)

Comment: Yes, just calling the sub again and being redirected.  And that is an interesting piece of information.  Rest assured, I'm not up to any nefarious acts.  I'd be the worst hacker in the world, hitting up forums every 3 minutes making a fool of myself.  Just trying to build a nice password protected Home Budget dashboard to be a better grown up. And thanks for the help.